# JPA/Hibernate native query to get and entity and eagerly fetch its associations not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa

[Hibernate 5.2 docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#sql-entity-associations-query) says:

> It is possible to eagerly join the Phone and the Person entities to
>   avoid the possible extra roundtrip for initializing the many-to-one
>   association.
>
> Example 475. JPA native query selecting entities with joined
>   many-to-one association

```
List<Phone> phones = entityManager.createNativeQuery(
    "SELECT * " +
    "FROM Phone ph " +
    "JOIN Person pr ON ph.person_id = pr.id", Phone.class )
.getResultList();

for(Phone phone : phones) {
    Person person = phone.getPerson();
}
```

I'm running an example similar to this one. My query is just as simple as the above. But, when I do `phone.getPerson()` another query is sent to database to retrieve `Person`. I get no duplicate alias error nor column not found error. By running myself the query generated by Hibernate I can check that all the columns needed to fill both Entities are present.

Also tried the Hibernate alternative of the query. It didn't work. Besides `.addEntity()` and `.addJoin()` are deprecated (though still in the manual examples).